# How to handle null in Pattern.compile?

Tags: java, design-patterns

How to handle `null` when using `Pattern.compile`? I'm using the following line to compare strings:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s1).find()
```

There are some cases where `s1` can be `null` and obviously it throws `NullPointerException`. I know this could be handled by another `if` condition to `s1`, but I would like to know is there's an alternate solution.

EDIT

```
Iterator iter = sampleList().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    SampleObj so = (SampleObj) iter.next();
    if (!s1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s1), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(so.getS1()).find())
            match = true;
        else
            match = false;
    }
    if (!s3.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s3), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(so.getS3()).find())
            match = true;
        else
            match = false;
    }
}
```

`s1` and `s3` are inputs which are matched over iterator.

Comment: @What is the expected behavior for `null` in your case?

Comment: @Dewfy Though it is null, I expect no null pointer exception should be thrown. I expect no explicit "if" condition should be written to check null

Comment: I don't know why you'd write it that way in the first place. Pattern.compile() should be called once, not every time you use the pattern. That's the whole idea. Compilation is expensive, use is cheap. You might as well just use Pattern.matches() if you need to recompile every time, i.e. if the regex is dynamic.

Comment: @EJP How do you want me to use Pattern.matches() instead of calling Pattern.compile() in loop? I have added the code in my question.

Comment: see the Javadoc for Pattern, the part starting 'A matches method is defined by this class as a convenience for when a regular expression is used just once.'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Pattern.matcher()` will always throw a `NullPointerException` when you pass in `null`, so: no, there is no other way, you'll have to check for `null` explicitly.

Comment: Java denied for checking null as part of Pattern class. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6178785

Answer (score 9):

You have to check for null; e.g.,

```
if(s1 != null && Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s1).find()))
```

Comment: There are two possible ways `s1 == null` *should* execute the `if`-body, or it shouldn't. You posted the second possibility, for the first you'd use `if (s1 == null || Pattern....`.

Comment: Very true. I'm making the assumption that the `s2` pattern does not match `null`, but that's OP's call.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
String.valueOf(s1)
```

which results in having "null" instead of null.